# how to create installer inside another installer?

Tags: windows, installation

I want to create a Windows Installer, the 1st step I want it to call another installer (will install dependent components of my application), and the 2nd step I want to install my own application. I want to do all tasks in one installation process, and I have the dependent component installation package at hand (an exe file).

Any good tools or samples to refer to? I prefer to use VSTS or Microsoft or open source easy to use tools. :-)

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 6):

You might want to take a look at the [Microsoft Bootstrapper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163899.aspx), assuming the dependent components are libraries such as .NET or similar then it's fairly straightforward.

If you want to create a [Windows Installer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Installer) (MSI) package then take a look at [Windows Installer XML](http://wix.sf.net) (WiX). But you'll want to [get your head around how MSI works](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590592972) first. WiX is really simple once you understand Windows Installer, but trying to learn both at once  can be rather confusing.

For a basic, copy some files, extract/run some stuff, type installer then [NSIS](http://nsis.sf.net) is fairly straightforward scripting and you can pick that up in a day or so.

Answer (score 4):

Nsis with [this modification](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Embedding_other_installers).

Answer (score 3):

Update: It seems that nesting MSI installation is somewhat possible. However it requires some tweaking using tools from the Windows Installer SDK and has a number of drawbacks.

The following article has the details:

> [How to create a nested .msi package](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306439)

Microsoft recommends not to use this feature (see this [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/88078/can-a-msi-file-install-itself-presumably-via-a-custom-action/90094#90094) and point 20 in this [list](http://blogs.msdn.com/windows_installer_team/archive/2006/05/12/595950.aspx)).

However, you might also want to look at different install systems such as NSIS or create a bootstrapper that installs the dependencies prior to setup.

Answer (score 1):

You could look at [Inno Setup](http://www.innosetup.com/). It creates exe installers, as opposed to MSIs. It has a pascal-based scripting language, so is pretty flexible.

It's free and pretty easy to use.

If your existing installer doesn't use the MSI technology, you could use [WiX](http://wix.sourceforge.net/) to create an MSI and launch the existing installer via a custom action. I've done this in the past.

WiX is open source.

Answer (score 1):

yes it would be very easy if you do it using Inno Setup, but with a slight difference..

You will have to perform step 2 first and then step 1.

Try using AutoHotkey(scripting) for checking the existence of any process in the background that verifies the installation of a particular software.

Answer (score 1):

Check out iexpress on windows systems. In just a few minutes you can create an installer that can call as many installers as you like.