# Two package resource is not installing continuously in Powershell DSC

Tags: powershell, dsc

I am using Package Resource to install the MSIs and EXEs in PowerShell DSC. I am using pull modal. I am triggering the Consistency Job to check the configurations is applied or not for testing.(Unable to wait 30 mins for single testing :) ) Here is My code.

```
   Package OpenDeploy
        {
         Name = "Interwoven OpenDeploy 6.2.0 Receiver"
         Path = "D:\Deployments\Prerequisites\IWOVopendeployRcvr.exe"
         ProductId = ''
         DependsOn = "[File]CopyPrerequisites"
         Ensure = "Present"
         Arguments = '/s /f1"D:\Deployments\Prerequisites\setup.iss"'
        }
       Package InstallMSXML
        {
         Name = "MSXML4.0"
         Path = "D:\Deployments\Prerequisites\msxml4.0_SP3.msi"
         ProductId = "XXXX67F1-C11F-4F76-858B-5812ADC83B94"
         DependsOn = "[File]CopyPrerequisites"
         Ensure = "Present"
        }
        Package Install_WebSite
        {
         Name = " Install_WebSite"
         Path = "D:\Deployments\Prerequisites\Install_WebSite.msi"
         ProductId = "XXXX3F53-982D-470C-9036-1DDFF81EC8B3"
         DependsOn = "[File]CopyPrerequisites"
         Ensure = "Present"
        }
```

When I run the Job, one package is installing at time. The another package is installing next time and so on. We need to install 10+ installers. If one at time then configuration will take more than a day to configure completely if one installation happen on every 30 Mins.

Is this there anyway to install all packages at once?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do these programs depend on each other?  Can they be installed in any order?

Comment: No this programs not depends on each other. They can be installed in any order.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're installing MSI's, DSC isn't your limitation ([How to run multiple msi files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1954034/how-to-run-multiple-msi-files)).  Don't look at DSC as a "performance" improvement.  It is more about ensuring once the server is created/configured you know the precise state (versus a manual install) and you can keep the server in the desired state.

If your provisioning VM's or using a Docker-like technology, consider creating on instance and then saving and ami or container to provision additional instances from...if you're not virtualized, you need to be...