# Automatically install project A when project B installs

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms

In one solution I have 2 projects winform Vb.net and C #. In the release environment, is there a way to run the vb.net project, and the C # project is also open?
On the first run after release, the vb.net project will be installed, how will the C # project be installed simultaneously?

Solution

+ProjectA vb.net(winform)

+ProjectB C#(winform)

[Project A call exe of ProjectB when start]

Comment: What is `B`? Is it dll? Sure, reference it and call. Is it exe? Sure, use `Process.Start()`. As for installer, what is *"on the first run after release, the vb.net project will be installed"*? What you call *installer* and *release environment*? And sure, installer can be written in a way to install all pre-requisites, including .Net Framework itself.

Comment: We need more info. There is no problem having both in one solution. If one only ever calls the other (in one direction) it's easy.  It becomes harder if Project A calls dependencies in Project B and Project B also has dependencies in Project A, although this is still possible as I work on a project like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a multifile assembly, contains both the C# part and the VB part. Inside the assembly, one project could then use the other. This would probably mean that you have to compile and link from the command line, though.

Maybe you could use a bootstrapper installer as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1954149/12342386 .

It is not entirely clear if you need to call the other project at installation time, or every time you start the first project. Your best answer will need to meet that requirement.