# cpack MSI installation exceeding 2GB - packing into multiple CAB files

Tags: cmake, wix, wix3.5, cpack

I am using cpack and Wix to create an MSI installer containing media files.
I am getting catastrophic failure, I read, [due to cabinet file exceeding 2GB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55295201/wix-toolset-bundle-with-total-content-size-2gb).
If I understand correctly, I can split the installation package into multiple CAB files.
Simplified CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(content 1.0.0 LANGUAGES CXX)

install(DIRECTORY video
  DESTINATION "."
  FILES_MATCHING REGEX ".+\.(avi|mp4)")

install(DIRECTORY images
  DESTINATION "."
  FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.png")

set(CPACK_WIX_PATCH_FILE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/misc/wix_patch.xml")
include(CPack)
```

I am not sure if it is correct, but I can [add more media elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2290647/wix-utilizing-multiple-cabs-in-a-very-large-application) in wix_patch.xml:

```
<CPackWiXPatch>
    <CPackWiXFragment Id="#PRODUCT">
        <Media Id='2' Cabinet='package1.cab' EmbedCab='no'/> 
        <Media Id='3' Cabinet='package2.cab' EmbedCab='no'/>
    </CPackWiXFragment>
</CPackWiXPatch>
```

Now the question arises, how can I assign DiskId attribute to files included in the CMake file?
How can I split files into these cabinet files?

If I am correct, in Wix file I would write:

```
<File Source="./vid.mp4" DiskId="2" />
```

To assign vid.mp4 file to package2.cab.
How can I achieve that using CPack?

Comment: [Some comments here on deploying large media files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53905088/129130).

Comment: Online is not an option and FAT32 is not a concern.
I am trying to make use of cpack here.

Comment: One of the solutions would be to instruct WIX to add to each file in files.wxs DiskId, but I have no idea if it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you don't need to deal with cabinet files at all.

Starting from Wix 3.6 you can use `<MediaTemplate/>` to let Wix automatically generate multiple cabinets. See http://www.joyofsetup.com/2011/06/21/wix-and-cabinetry/

However, to use this with CPack, you have to specify your own template file using `CPACK_WIX_TEMPLATE` as the default template (https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/blob/master/Modules/Internal/CPack/WIX.template.in) uses `<Media/>` which cannot coexist with `<MediaTemplate/>`.