# WiX Custom Action - MSI copy itself

Tags: wix, custom-action

Can someone help me to build a custom action in MSI which will copy itself after successful installation to some X location.
I have already seen it can be done using .exe but I want to do it only with CA.DLL (C#) as this exe will be an overhead.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can a .msi file install itself (presumably via a Custom Action)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/88078/can-a-msi-file-install-itself-presumably-via-a-custom-action)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example VB script that will find an installed product by name and copy the cached copy of the MSI. This will work on Windows 7 and later, as the full MSI is cached and any embedded cab files remain in the MSI. You just get the MSI without the payload on older systems.

```vb
Dim installer, products, product, productCode
Set installer = Wscript.CreateObject("WindowsInstaller.Installer")

For Each productCode In installer.Products
  If InStr(1, LCase(installer.ProductInfo(productCode, "ProductName")), LCase("My Product Name")) Then Exit For
Next

If IsEmpty(productCode) Then Wscript.Quit 2

Set products = installer.ProductsEx(productCode, "", 7)
filesys.copyFile products(0).InstallProperty("LocalPackage"), "c:\path\to\newcopy.msi"
```