# Installshield 2013 Installscript MSI: Wrong .msi location during Repair

Tags: installshield

I've got a pretty simple installscript MSI project - it copies some files into a folder, updates a few registry keys and that's pretty much it.

When I try to use the Repair function (either by re-launching the installer, or by choosing the app's Modify option under Apps & Features), I get the following message, when it gets to the "Copying new files" stage:

> "The feature you are trying to use is on a network resource that is unavailable.
>
> Click OK to try again, or enter an alternate path to a folder containing the installation package 'project.msi' in the box below."

The path in which it looks for the .msi file is `%TEMP%\[SOME_RANDOM_HEXADECIMAL_STRING]`

This random hexadecimal string doesn't seem to be specifically related to the project. It's neither the Product Code nor the Upgrade Code nor the Package Code.

When I look for it in the registry, I find it in the values of the following keys:

```
Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Installer\Products\[SCRAMBLED_PRODUCT_CODE]\SourceList\LastUsedSource
Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Installer\Products\[SCRAMBLED_PRODUCT_CODE]\SourceList\Net\3
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Installer\Products\[ANOTHER_SCRAMBLED_PRODUCT_CODE]\SourceList\LastUsedSource
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Installer\Products\[ANOTHER_SCRAMBLED_PRODUCT_CODE]\SourceList\Net\3
```

Looking at the `%TEMP%` folder, I can find the .msi file in a folder that has another random hexadecimal string as its name. That folder does not appear in the registry at all.

I don't want my clients to go looking for .msi files every time they want to repair an installation of my product. How can I let the installer know the .msi file's location?

Answer (score 1):

The source files you installed from are probably just missing since your temp folder has been cleaned out (where the install originally ran from).

There used to be a `cache the whole MSI - feature` you could enable on a [release-configuration basis](http://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/isxhelp21/helplibrary/ReleaseGridSetupTab.htm) (`Cache MSI Locally`). This would "solve" this problem I believe by [caching the whole MSI in a safe location](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48823086/129130) (see section 3). Many do this, despite the increased disk space used.

Another option is to install from an [administrative installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5564619/what-is-the-purpose-of-administrative-installation-initiated-using-msiexec-a/5751980#5751980) (essentially an extract of your setup's files - run via `setup.exe /a` or `msiexec.exe /a MySetup.msi` - which has been put available on a network share, always available for repair or modify operations). This is what corporate deployment uses to support repair and modify operations.

Comment: Thanks Stein.
I eventually managed to fix the issue by changing the release type from Single Image to a custom one, with multiple files. 

It may have the same effect as the "cache the whole MSI" feature you suggested, but I didn't go too deep on that. When it comes the Installshield, I'm just glad it works.